# unique_ptr in member initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, unique-ptr

**EDIT:** I understand unique_ptr is non-copyable and can be only moved. i do not understand what happens with the initialization list.

Why unique_ptr in member initialization list can work as in the code snipt?

```
#include <memory>

class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject() : ptr(new int) // this works.
    MyObject() : ptr(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)) 
    // i found this in many examples. but why this also work? 
    // i think this is using copy constructor as the bottom.        
    {
    }

    MyObject(MyObject&& other) : ptr(std::move(other.ptr))
    {
    }

    MyObject& operator=(MyObject&& other)
    {
        ptr = std::move(other.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int main() {
    MyObject o;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr (new int);
    // compile error, of course, since copy constructor is not allowed. 
    // but what is happening with member initialization list in above?
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr2(ptr); 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example, `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)` is an rvalue, so the move-constructor of `ptr` is used.

The second time (in `main`), `std::unique_ptr<int> ptr2(ptr)` doesn't work because `ptr` is an lvalue, and cannot be moved directly (you can use `std::move`).

Answer (score 15):

This is to do with *named* and *unnamed* objects.

When you do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int);
//                   ^^^--- name is 'ptr'
```

But when you do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int>(new int);
//                  ^--where is the name??
```

If an object is created without a name it is called a *temporary* or an *r-value* and the compiler has different rules for *r-values* than it does for *named objects* or *l-values*.

Named objects (*l-values*) can only be *copied* to another object but unnamed objects (*r-values*) can either be *copied* or *moved*.

In your example you use a `std::unique_ptr`. These objects can only be *moved* because they have had their copy semantics disabled. This is why your compiler is giving an error when you try to *copy* one:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr (new int);
// compile error, copy constructor delete
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr2(ptr); // copy is disabled!!
```

Here `ptr` is a *named object* so it can *only be copied* but its *copy semantics* are disabled so the whole operation is illegal.

BUT when you do a similar thing with an *unnamed object* like this:

```
MyObject() : ptr(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)) 
                                     ^--- look no name!!!
```

Then the compiler can either *copy* or *move* and it always tries to *move* before trying to *copy*.

The `std::unique_ptr` is fully *move complaint* so the compiler has no complaints.

Comment: I cannot accept two answers. I picked the one from Nelxiost, since it is more succinct

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObject() : ptr(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int))
```

that uses the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr` (from a temporary).

You might change your `main` into

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr2(std::move(ptr));
```

to compile

Comment: Of course, that's only a good idea if the OP actually wants to *move* the pointer rather than, say, having two smart pointers to the object where the right fix is very different.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Indeed, if OP wants to share ownership, `std::shared_ptr` should be used instead of `std::unique_ptr`, and keep the copy.